# Angular js directive call with controller data binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ionic-view

**View**

```
<star-rating ratingValue="ratings" readonly="true"></star-rating>
<div><strong>Rating 1:</strong>{{ratings}}</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('ProductCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $resource, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $compile, $ionicPopup, $location, $sce) {
        $scope.ratings  = 0;
        this.isReadonly = true;
        this.rateFunction = function(rating) {
          console.log('Rating selected: ' + rating);
        };

        $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $http.get(web_service + 'product/get', {
            params: {id: $stateParams.ProductId},
            headers: {}
        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.product = response.product;
            console.log(response.product);
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
            $scope.ratings = response.product.rating;
            this.rateFunction = function(rating) {
                console.log('Rating selected: ' + rating);
            };
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            alert("ERROR");
        });

    }).directive('starRating', starRating);
```

**Directive**

```
function starRating() {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template:
        '<ul class="star-rating" ng-class="{readonly: readonly}">' +
        '  <li ng-repeat="star in stars" class="star" ng-class="{filled: star.filled}" ng-click="toggle($index)">' +
        '    <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>' + // or &#9733
        '  </li>' +
        '</ul>',
      scope: {
        ratingValue: '=?',
        max: '=?', // optional (default is 5)
        onRatingSelect: '&?',
        readonly: '=?'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        if (scope.max == undefined) {
          scope.max = 5;
        }
        scope.$observe('ratingValue', function(value){
            console.log(value);
            //$scope.nav.selection = value
        });
        function updateStars() {
          scope.stars = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
            scope.stars.push({
              filled: i < scope.ratingValue
            });
          }
        };
        scope.toggle = function(index) {
          if (scope.readonly == undefined || scope.readonly === false){
            scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
            scope.onRatingSelect({
              rating: index + 1
            });
          }
        };
        scope.$watch('ratingValue', function(oldValue, newValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            updateStars();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

> When initial value of **$scope.ratings**  is number like 1,2,3 then starts prints  but the value retrieved by ajax request is not getting added to directive and in directive values shows **"undefined"** and no starts getting printed.

The tag below directive in view code gives retrieved value referring to this Codepen: http://codepen.io/TepigMC/pen/FIdHb

What I am missing in directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ng-if so that the directive is called after you have $scope.ratings.

```
<star-rating ng-if="ratings" ratingValue="ratings" readonly="true"></star-rating>
```

Comment: <div><strong>Rating 1:</strong>{{ratings}}</div> if i add this then i get value in ratings

Comment: It didnt work, because you template will be cached locally. After two to three refresh, or you must have deleted the cached file which loaded the latest code. That's why it worked.

Comment: yeah Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Wow! It's great answer! I want to master my Angular knowledge. What would you suggest me reading?

Comment: I dont suggest reading. I always try to reinvent the wheel and for the same issue i spent two days.  I went through angular in 60ish minutes and that was really helpful for my basics.